# Is mediation analysis for survival data equivalent to survival analysis with time-depent covariate adjustment?

Tags: r, multivariate-analysis, survival, mediation

Researching the topic of treatment duration on multiple clinical outcomes, some non-fatal which occur earlier and some fatal occurring later, I have stumbled upon mediation analysis (eg [Zhang et al, Ann Transl Med 2016](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5124624/pdf/atm-04-21-425.pdf)), which is already available in the [mediation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mediation/mediation.pdf) R package.

It appears to me that there is substantial conceptual overlap, at least when focusing on mediation analysis for survival data, with survival analysis with time-dependent covariate adjustment. Is this correct? Or does instead mediation analysis truly add important insights into outcome mediation?

Comment: I added the `mediation` tag to your question. Please read its [info page](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/mediation/info) and look over some of its [highly voted questions](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mediation?sort=votes). Note that the [`mediation` package](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=mediation) at present only seems to allow for parametric survival models, not Cox proportional hazards models.